# drop down menu using css ! wont work with FF

Tags: firefox, focus

Well just like the title says,
I have created a drop down menu that turns from display:none; to display:block;
when clicking to parent li element.

when it comes down to testing, it seems to works as expected with
Safari & Chrome.
when tested with IE & FF, the expected result will trigger only if you click at the
bottom of the li#mtfw scope, when clicking the link with Safari, it doesn’t matter
where you click the drop down menu will appear! 
here is the example page & the css code 
http://www.incapsulatest.tk/test/example.html

P.S using the :focus selector on non input type is possible only because i am using tabindex on the element.

Comment: Your code doesn't validate. Please make it validate first: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.incapsulatest.tk%2Ftest%2Fexample.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: this file is html5, why would you validate it using a tool testing for html 4

Comment: + it returns errors because of the free hosting adding a counter on the end of the page